# Angular chart tooltop animation not working

Tags: angular-chart

I have an Angular Chart Bar-Line chart, and it works, but the tooltop is different of this:http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/examples/stacked-bars.html

My chart tooltip is "static" like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/masiht/r5g6a3cd/

```
<div id="chart-area"><canvas id="bar" width="250" height="250" style="width:250px; height: 250px;"></canvas> <div id="legend"></div></div>
```

My own have no animation and dont show the "arrow head" in tooltops.

I tried adding css, bootstrap and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change animation to true:

```
var bar = new Chart(canvas.getContext('2d')).Bar(barChartData, {
  tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>kb",
  animation: true,
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it dont work on angular chart, or not for my :(